# Color Picker Tool is not being shown in the gutter area Intellij IDEA for CSS files

Tags: css, intellij-idea, color-picker

I am editing a CSS files in `Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2016.2`. However the color picker tool is not being shown in gutter area (even though the respective setting is checked).

Any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Try entering on a blank line

```
p {
    background-color:
```

You should get an auto-complete option for colors, and the default one is `choose color` which shows the color picker.

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/uR-a5ZVJFLo) showing that.

Comment: Appreciate your response but no luck.

Comment: Aww... could you recreate what I showed in the video?

Comment: No. Looks like it is only supported in Ultimate Edition. Guess you are using one :)

Comment: Aww... that stinks. If you are a student or teacher you can get all JetBrains apps for free, etc. more detail [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/#edition=discounts)